# Storing and fetching files in an openshift web application

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, filesystems, openshift

I am working on a web application which will have functionality to upload, store files as well as fetch and display files. I am planning to deploy the application in openshift.

Please suggest how to store and retrieve the files. Will the files be stored in DB (MySQL) or filesystem considering the performance of the application?

Comment: Uploads would be stored on your server in a specific folder. As for displaying, you would simply point back to this folder.

Comment: Ultimately depends on the nature of the data. But if arbitrary files, use the file system as already note by @NoelMurphy. Just remember that you will need to make a persistent volume claim to get a persistent volume and then mount that into the application container. Write the files to the persistent volume. If don't write to a persistent volume all your files will be lost on a restart as filesystem is otherwise ephemeral.

Comment: File types will be mainly doc, pdf and excel. I am planning to claim for additional persistent volume based on the file size. Do you have any reference on how to access the openshift file system using java either to store or fetch the data?

Comment: There is no special API. The persistent volume is mounted like a disk. Use the normal APIs you would use to interact with the file system, create files, write files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goals:

- You need to store files, that are a type of persistent objects ;
- You need to do that in an OpenShift environment.

So, you should consider using **Persistent Volumes (PV)**, that come with Kubernetes, the underlying management plan for containers used by OpenShift.

The PV subsystem provides an API that abstracts details of how storage is provided and how it is consumed, so you can choose one of the many backends that most fits your needs. For instance, you could choose Persistent Volumes based on GlusterFS, to have high-availability. You could also choose iSCSI, NFS, etc. depending on the infrastructure you already own.

See [OpenShift persistent volumes](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html) guide.

You could also use the DB to store paths to your files on your persistent volumes. Writing to those files with Java is as easy as using the standard `java.io` package.

But using a DB to track files on remote dynamic volumes is a kind of reinventing an Object Storage system. So, you could also look at the [Swift SAAS](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/) (Storage as a Service) subsystem from the OpenStack community. It is available from a JSON/REST API, so it would be very easy to access it from your JEE environment.

PV are certainly easier to integrate than Swift (Swift needs KeyStone at least, to be able to offer services, so there are two OpenStack subsystems to deploy if you want SAAS with REST/JSON API).